# How to start the web application with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I am reading this tutorial now.

- [Tutorial · Building web applications with Spring Boot and Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/)

The tutorial say

> Start the web application by running the main function of BlogApplication.kt, and go to http://localhost:8080/, you should see a sober web page with a "Blog" headline.

How to start the web application with Spring Boot and Kotlin?

I wrote `BlogApplication.kt` as below according to the tutorial

```
package com.example.blog

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class BlogApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<BlogApplication>(*args)
}
```

I use `Gradle`.

Comment: Did you try the Gradle run task? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#running_applications

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @DiegoMagdaleno I edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. In your IDE, right click the `main` function and choose "Run"
2. With Gradle, in your terminal, run `./gradlew bootRun`